# How to prepare for GPU upgrade (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 TI) on Debian 9.5

Tags: debian, nvidia

I am replacing the old GPU Quadro FX 580 running on Nouvea drivers on Debian 9.5.

I am going to install NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 TI GPU possibly with the latest Nvidia propriatery drivers (currently these are NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.66)

My current kernel version is

```
$cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.9.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6 (2018-10-08)
```

Loaded nouveau modules:

```
$ lsmod | grep nouveau
nouveau              1556480  4
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    16384  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  1 nouveau
ttm                    98304  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 nouveau
drm                   360448  7 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
button                 16384  1 nouveau
```

Some additional info :

```
$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA G96GL [Quadro FX 580] bus-ID: 05:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.2 drivers: nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1200@59.95hz, 1920x1200@59.95hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on NV96 GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

My question is how to prepare the whole operation in order to go smoothly through whe upgrade process:

What steps should be taken before I take out the old GPU and inster the new one, e.g.

1. What configuration files should I backup

   - Should I install some packages first
   - Should I uninstall some packages
   - Should I update configuration files
   - Should I update blacklists
   - Should I update the kernel
2. What steps should be taken after the installation of the new GPU.

   - Should I install the drivers from NVIDIA site by running their .run file or rather install the older version drivers from debian repository
   - Will the desktop environment (XFCE) run on Nouvea drivers after reboot before new drivers are installed?

I have found [NVidia GTX 1080 installation on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://abhay.harpale.net/blog/linux/nvidia-gtx-1080-installation-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) step-by-step guide but It relates to Ubintu 16.04 which is running different kernel, also not a TI version, so not sure if I won't run in some issues by following its steps.

Comment: i would check out first the official debian wiki for insight on the matter https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers